# PHP Codeigniter - Email function not working on server

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, email, codeigniter-2

I write the following code to sent emails from my localhost. It works fine on my localhost but when I uploaded the file to the server, it stopped working. Following is my code:

```
public function Sent_Confirmation_Email()
        {
        $emailid  = $this->uri->segment(3);

        $verificationLink = base_url() . 'MainController/Confirm_Activation/'.$emailid;

        $msg .= "Thank you for creating an account with us.<br /><br /><br />";
        $msg .= " Please <a href='".$verificationLink."' target='_blank'>Click Here</a> to verify your email.<br /><br /><br />";
        $msg .= "Kind regards,<br />";
        $msg .= "Real Animation Works.";


        if( ! ini_get('date.timezone') )
        {
        date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
        }        

        $config = Array('protocol' => 'smtp',
                        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
                        'smtp_port' => 465,
                        'smtp_user' => 'myemail@gmail.com',
                        'smtp_pass' => 'mypassword' 
        );

        $this->load->library('email',$config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
        //$this->email->isHTML(true);
        $this->email->from("myemail@gmail.com");
        $this->email->to("$emailid");
        $this->email->subject("Email Confirmation - Courses and Tutors");
        $this->email->message($msg);

        if($this->email->send())
        {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'A confirmation email has been sent to ' . $emailid .'. Please activate your account using the link provided.');
        redirect(base_url() . 'MainController/EConfirmationPage/'.$emailid);
        } else {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
        }
        }
```

Following is the screenshot of the error which I get when I run the code:

[image]

[image]

Comment: From your attached image, it says "Failed to Authenticate Password ". Have you checked this?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
function Sent_Confirmation_Email()
{
    $this->load->library('email'); # Added

    $emailid  = $this->uri->segment(3);

    $verificationLink = base_url() . 'MainController/Confirm_Activation/'.$emailid;

    $msg .= "Thank you for creating an account with us.<br /><br /><br />";
    $msg .= " Please <a href='".$verificationLink."' target='_blank'>Click Here</a> to verify your email.<br /><br /><br />";
    $msg .= "Kind regards,<br />";
    $msg .= "Real Animation Works.";


    if( ! ini_get('date.timezone') )
    {
        date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
    }        

    $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
    $config['smtp_port'] = '465';
    $config['smtp_user'] = 'myemail@gmail.com';
    $config['smtp_pass'] = 'password';
    $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';  # Added
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html'; # Added
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

    $this->email->initialize($config);  # Added
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

    $this->email->from("myemail@gmail.com");
    $this->email->to($emailid);  # Changed
    $this->email->subject("Email Confirmation - Courses and Tutors");
    $this->email->message($msg);

    if(!$this->email->send())  # Changed
    {
        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
    } 
    else 
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'A confirmation email has been sent to ' . $emailid .'. Please activate your account using the link provided.');
        redirect(base_url() . 'MainController/EConfirmationPage/'.$emailid); # Not sure in this part.
    }
}
```